# How to prepend a domain to all images

Tags: regex, web

```
  let bar = "<img src=\"/assets/img/screenshot-scripts.png\" alt=\"scripts screenshot\" class=\"half center\" /><img src=\"/assets/img/screenshot-scripts-sed.png\" alt=\"scripts sed screenshot\" />";
bar = bar.replaceAll(/src=\\"(.*)\\"/gi, 'src="https://blog.jonesrussell.xyz/$1"');
```

This does not produce the desired results of https://blog.jonesrussell42.xyz being prepended to all image src's.

Comment: `/src="(.*?)"/gi`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd use RegExp for this (generally speaking, it's not the right tool to do any HTML parsing/maipulation with so many edge cases out there). You could use [`DOMParser.parseFromString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and do the manipulation properly:

```js
let domain = "https://blog.jonesrussell.xyz";
let bar = "<img src=\"/assets/img/screenshot-scripts.png\" alt=\"scripts screenshot\" class=\"half center\" /><img src=\"/assets/img/screenshot-scripts-sed.png\" alt=\"scripts sed screenshot\" />";
var htmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(bar, 'text/html');

for (image of [...htmlDoc.querySelectorAll('img')]) {
  image.src = domain + image.getAttribute('src'); // use getAttribute() to ensure the parser doesn't try to automatically evaluate the `src` property to the current domain before being able to prepend our own domain value
  console.log(image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex to manipulate HTML is not reliable. As @esqew pointed out, it is safer to use an HTML parser.

If you are Ok not supporting corner cases you can use this regex:

```js
let bar = "<img src=\"/assets/img/screenshot-scripts.png\" alt=\"scripts screenshot\" class=\"half center\" /><img src=\"/assets/img/screenshot-scripts-sed.png\" alt=\"scripts sed screenshot\" />";
bar = bar.replace(/\b(src=["']?)/gi, '$1https://blog.jonesrussell.xyz');
console.log(bar);
```

Output:
`<img src="https://blog.jonesrussell.xyz/assets/img/screenshot-scripts.png" alt="scripts screenshot" class="half center" /><img src="https://blog.jonesrussell.xyz/assets/img/screenshot-scripts-sed.png" alt="scripts sed screenshot" />`

Explanation:

- `\b` - word boundary to reduce the chance of false positives
- `(src=["']?)` - expect and capture `src="`,  `src='`, or a  `src=` without quotes
- in the replacement, use the captured group `$1`, and add the domain

You could use a positive lookbehind to avoid the capture group with `$1`, but Safari does not yet support that.

Comment: @Russell: Any questions? Does this fit your needs?

Comment: @Russell: If helpful, care to accept the answer?